# No usb serial on Mac

Tags: programming, serial

I've been using my Arduino UNO without a hith for a few days now, but suddenly I can't program it anymore.

When I try to programm my Arduino on Mac, I get the following Error:

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

The USB option under serial port has disappeard (It was there before). Has anyone an idea on how to fix this?

The last thing I did is use the serial port for some communication. A reboot hasn't improved anything.

I tried programming Linux, but it resulted in the exact same result.

Comment: Related: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/804/arduino-nano-uploading-gives-error-avrdude-stk500-recv-programmer-is-not-re Does that solve your issue? What board are you using?

Comment: No is doesn't solve the problem. Besides that: I use an original Arduino Uno.

Comment: On Linux go to computer>var>lock and delete the  serial port lock files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seemed to be a hardware problem on the board. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: You could try [re-flashing the firmware](http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/DFUProgramming8U2) for the usb-to-serial chip (atmega8u2) on the uno board.

Answer (score 1):

If I try to upload with no device connected, I get a dialog with the message "port is blocked" and a message in Eclipse's console window that the port is not found.

So I'm guessing you've got a sync problem. UNO should reset automatically when avrdude connects. Try manually resetting it just before you click to start the download. If that works, then the automatic reset has failed.

Comment: If I try to upload with no device connected, I still get: "avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding"