# How to set cables to connect CP2102 to Pro Mini?

Tags: programming, usb, pins, arduino-pro-mini, wires

How to connect the cables in order to program the pro mini with the CP2102 usb interface ?
The TX RX and GND is easy, but I am not sure about the RST, DTR, DST, etc

[image: CP2102 and Pro Mini]

When I try cables like this:

```
TX  ... RX
RX  ... TX
5V  ... VCC // my pro mini is 5V version
GND ... GND
RST ... RST
```

The board lits up and green starts blinking, this should be the default `blinker` program.

I click Upload, I get this error, and I assume the cables are not properly connected:

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x89
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x89
```

I know some people mentioned it works by adding some resistor and capacitor, but I was hoping that is an error and it should work without that complication.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what works for me:

```
Pro Mini  ---------   CP2102

  DTR     ---------    DTR
  RST     ---------    RST   (optional if you wish to press some buttons)

  GND     ---------    GND
  RX      ---------    TX
  TX      ---------    RX
  VCC     ---------    VCC
```

---

*Tap on the image to see the HD image*

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYENt.jpg]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVkNp.jpg]

Answer (score -1):

RST to RST. Ignore the others, they are irrelevant.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, I updated my questions with error details.

Answer (score -1):

Pretty sure RST is Reset input to the CP2102, that will not work.

DTR to DTR (BLK on the Promini) will work, the DTR Low level goes thru the Promini's 0.1uF cap and 10K Reset pullup resistor to make a Reset pulse. That's how the FTDI Basic works when connected.

RTS (Request To Send output) might also work, that is supposedly a pulsed level.

Comment: same errors, I tried the `DTR` and `RTS` pins from USB to pins from pro mini (`RST`, `BLK`) in all combinations.

Comment: You meant to *add* a 10K resistor ?

Comment: The Promini's I've used http://store.yahoo.com/yhst-27389313707334/arpromi5v.html have the 0.1uF cap and 10K pullup resistor on board. All that was needed for programming was to connect an FTDI Basic directly to it, pin to pin.   http://www.tinyosshop.com/download/Pro-Mini.sch.pdf

Comment: Are you positive your Promini has a bootloader installed?

Comment: I have no ideea, it seems to have blinker program installed, does it mean the bootloader is already there ?

Comment: OK, I heard enough times about the `0.1uF cap and 10K pullup resistor` [https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=231863.0], I am going to the store now :)