# Unable to Upload

Tags: atmega328

Not able to upload sketches to standalone arduino on breadboard (with Atmega328 bootloaded with blink LED program). Searched on the internet but there is no solution. Help ?

error : 
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00

OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: if you have something connected to digital pins 0 or 1 (rx/ tx), disconnect, and try to upload.

Comment: no improvement.. :(

Comment: The board is selected properly? If it still doesn't work, there is a bug somewhere... Also found on internet, in fact on arduino stackexchange (http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/804/arduino-nano-uploading-gives-error-avrdude-stk500-recv-programmer-is-not-re) that you have to press reset just before uploading... Also try: http://www.instructables.com/id/A-solution-to-avrdude-stk500getsync-not-in-syn/ and http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=273910.0. Maybe will help you!

Comment: When you say" Bootloaded with blink program " - should this read, " bootloaded with bootloader program " by any chance? You have actually got a bootloader in? How else did you get "blink" on it?

Comment: @MarkWilliams Thank you for correction but that doesn't solved my problem in any way.

Comment: got it 
http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/106870/programming-an-atmega328-with-arduino-bootloader-via-a-ftdi-usb-serial-adapter

Comment: Does this mean the question is resolved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["avrdude: stk500\_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00," aka Some Dude Named Avr Won't Let Me Upload My Program](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17/avrdude-stk500-getsync-not-in-sync-resp-0x00-aka-some-dude-named-avr-won)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the RX, TX pins are not connected to any other circuit when uploading sketches.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the board selected and port selected are correct. I face this problem many time but they disappear after I remove my other circuit connection and reconnect my arduino board to pc