# CH340 Nano avrdude: stk500_getsync() not in sync resp=0xa4

Tags: uploading, windows, ch340

I'm trying to upload some code to an non-arduino nano with the CH340G chip, and the avrdude refuses to let me upload. The error I'm getting is:

```
Using Port                    : COM4
Using Programmer              : arduino
Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xf6
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xf6
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xf6
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xf6
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xf6
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xf6
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xf6
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xf6
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xf6
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xf6

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

I've tried installing the drivers for the CH340 chip following [this guide](http://woodsgood.ca/projects/2014/11/18/driver-for-arduino-nano-with-ch340g-usb-chip/) but have had no luck. I've also tried uploading to my arduino uno and my arduino micro (both are arduino brand) with no problems. I'm running Windows 10, Arduino IDE 1.8.5

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks, this was my issue as well, Arduino Nano from side manufacturer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arduino Nano uploading gives error: avrdude: stk500\_recv(): programmer is not responding](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/804/arduino-nano-uploading-gives-error-avrdude-stk500-recv-programmer-is-not-re)

Comment: @scruss. it is not a duplicate. read the answer, check the dates

Comment: it sure is: it's an older question having the same problem. Sure, the accepted answer isn't any good, but [this one](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/51985/3692) is spot on

Comment: @scruss, the 'Old Bootloader' problem didn't exist 5 years ago when the other question was asked.

Answer (score 17):

Arduino has recently changed to using a different bootloader on their official Nano boards that communicates at 115200 baud rather than the previous 57600 baud. Support for these new boards was [added](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/commit/1b14cc07331268e95eddcce2cc67e29ed667e62f) in Arduino AVR Boards 1.6.21. The new Nano board definition is not compatible with old Nanos and likely most 3rd party Nanos so backwards compatibility is provided via the **Tools > Processor > ATmega328P (Old Bootloader)** menu selection.