# Arduino Nano 3.0 CH340G clone cannot upload sketch from Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino-nano, sketch, ide

I connected my brand new Arduino Nano 3.0 clone with CH340G and installed the drivers. It detects in Device Manager as USB-SERIAL CH340 (COM6). Under the Tools menu, i selected the correct board, the processor set to ATmega328P and the COM port. I couldn't upload my sketch so i tried uploading an example Blink sketch from Arduino IDE. The uploading is stuck. I keep waiting and nothing happens. I have read somewhere else that i should enable verbose output for compilation and upload, which i did and here is the output for trying to upload the basic Blink sketch.

```
Arduino: 1.8.9 (Windows 7), Board: "Arduino Nano, ATmega328P"

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware -hardware C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\tools-builder -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -tools C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages -built-in-libraries C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries -libraries C:\Users\admin\Documents\Arduino\libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:nano:cpu=atmega328 -vid-pid=1A86_7523 -ide-version=10809 -build-path C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_747566 -warnings=none -build-cache C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_890158 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2.path=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2 -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino14 -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.3.0-arduino14.path=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino14 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\arduinoOTA\1.2.1 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA-1.2.1.path=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\arduinoOTA\1.2.1 -verbose C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\examples\01.Basics\Blink\Blink.ino
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware -hardware C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\tools-builder -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -tools C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages -built-in-libraries C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries -libraries C:\Users\admin\Documents\Arduino\libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:nano:cpu=atmega328 -vid-pid=1A86_7523 -ide-version=10809 -build-path C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_747566 -warnings=none -build-cache C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_890158 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2.path=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2 -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino14 -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.3.0-arduino14.path=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino14 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\arduinoOTA\1.2.1 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA-1.2.1.path=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\arduinoOTA\1.2.1 -verbose C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\examples\01.Basics\Blink\Blink.ino
Using board 'nano' from platform in folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr
Using core 'arduino' from platform in folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr
Detecting libraries used...
"C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\tools\\avr-gcc\\5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10809 -DARDUINO_AVR_NANO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\cores\\arduino" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\variants\\eightanaloginputs" "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_747566\\sketch\\Blink.ino.cpp" -o nul
Generating function prototypes...
"C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\tools\\avr-gcc\\5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10809 -DARDUINO_AVR_NANO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\cores\\arduino" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\variants\\eightanaloginputs" "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_747566\\sketch\\Blink.ino.cpp" -o "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_747566\\preproc\\ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\tools-builder\\ctags\\5.8-arduino11/ctags" -u --language-force=c++ -f - --c++-kinds=svpf --fields=KSTtzns --line-directives "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_747566\\preproc\\ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"
Compiling sketch...
"C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\tools\\avr-gcc\\5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10809 -DARDUINO_AVR_NANO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\cores\\arduino" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\variants\\eightanaloginputs" "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_747566\\sketch\\Blink.ino.cpp" -o "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_747566\\sketch\\Blink.ino.cpp.o"
Compiling libraries...
Compiling core...
Using precompiled core: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_890158\core\core_arduino_avr_nano_cpu_atmega328_0c812875ac70eb4a9b385d8fb077f54c.a
Linking everything together...
"C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\tools\\avr-gcc\\5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2/bin/avr-gcc" -w -Os -g -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -o "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_747566/Blink.ino.elf" "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_747566\\sketch\\Blink.ino.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_747566/..\\arduino_cache_890158\\core\\core_arduino_avr_nano_cpu_atmega328_0c812875ac70eb4a9b385d8fb077f54c.a" "-LC:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_747566" -lm
"C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\tools\\avr-gcc\\5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2/bin/avr-objcopy" -O ihex -j .eeprom --set-section-flags=.eeprom=alloc,load --no-change-warnings --change-section-lma .eeprom=0 "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_747566/Blink.ino.elf" "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_747566/Blink.ino.eep"
"C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\tools\\avr-gcc\\5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2/bin/avr-objcopy" -O ihex -R .eeprom "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_747566/Blink.ino.elf" "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_747566/Blink.ino.hex"
"C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\tools\\avr-gcc\\5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2/bin/avr-size" -A "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_747566/Blink.ino.elf"
Sketch uses 930 bytes (3%) of program storage space. Maximum is 30720 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino14/bin/avrdude -CC:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino14/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -carduino -PCOM6 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_747566/Blink.ino.hex:i 
An error occurred while uploading the sketch

avrdude: Version 6.3-20171130
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino14/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM6
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xd8
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xd8
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xd8
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xd8
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xd8
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xd8
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xd8
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xd8
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xd8
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xd8

avrdude done.  Thank you.

Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
```

Comment: I have had cheap nano clones come from China without a bootloader installed. Try reinstalling the bootloader.

Comment: I searched and found that i would need a working Arduino Nano in order to transfer its working bootloader onto the non-working one. Is it possible to do it if i don't have another Arduino Nano?

Comment: Get yourself a USBASP off eBay/AliExpress/Amazon.

Comment: select "Old bootloader" in Tools menu

Comment: I followed these guides and i got it to work: https://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Burn-a-Bootloader-to-Clone-Arduino-Nano-30/ and https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/arduinoISP#toc2

Comment: so you burned the "new" bootloader

Comment: Yes, i assumed that the new bootloader is better and also that's what was recommended in the tutorial. What are the reasons for using or preferring the old bootloader?

Comment: if you can't burn the 'new' :-). The 'new' bootloader is the bootloader of Uno (so not really new). It is Arduino version of Optiboot 4. Really new is Optiboot 8.

Comment: OK, but i'm wondering what difference does it make? Does the 'old' bootloader enable faster compiling/upload/execution? Or does it make the board less power hungry??

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/51866/arduino-nano-atmega328p-bootloader-difference/51874#51874

Answer (score 1):

You normally just have to press 'reset' on the board button 1 sec before clicking 'Upload'.

I had to do this with cheap Nano clone.

Comment: MCU on Nano doesn't have native USB and has a different bootloader.